# C# multiple asynchronous HttpRequest with one callback

Tags: c#, asynchronous, httprequest

I want to make 10 asynchronous http requests at once and only process the results when all have completed and in a single callback function. I also do not want to block any threads using WaitAll (it is my understanding that WaitAll blocks until all are complete). I think I want to make a custom IAsyncResult which will handle multiple calls. Am I on the right track? Are there any good resources or examples out there that describe handling this?

Comment: What's the context of this operation? Inside a web page?

Comment: This sort of thing is very nearly trivial in F#. It might be worthwhile to write a module in F# that can be called from C# code...

Comment: @Keltex it would be part of a web application.

Comment: Are you talking about requesting data from multiple web pages?

Comment: @Scott P I'm calling multiple web service functions. I need all the results before I return my result to the user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I like Darin's solution.  But, if you want something more traditional, you can try this.

I would definitely use an array of wait handles and the WaitAll mechanism:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    WaitCallback del = state =>
    {
        ManualResetEvent[] resetEvents = new ManualResetEvent[10];
        WebClient[] clients = new WebClient[10];

        Console.WriteLine("Starting requests");
        for (int index = 0; index < 10; index++)
        {
            resetEvents[index] = new ManualResetEvent(false);
            clients[index] = new WebClient();

            clients[index].OpenReadCompleted += new OpenReadCompletedEventHandler(client_OpenReadCompleted);

            clients[index].OpenReadAsync(new Uri(@"http:\\www.google.com"), resetEvents[index]);
        }

        bool succeeded = ManualResetEvent.WaitAll(resetEvents, 10000);
        Complete(succeeded);

        for (int index = 0; index < 10; index++)
        {
            resetEvents[index].Dispose();
            clients[index].Dispose();
        }
    };

    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(del);

    Console.WriteLine("Waiting...");
    Console.ReadKey();
}

static void client_OpenReadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    // Do something with data...Then close the stream
    e.Result.Close();

    ManualResetEvent readCompletedEvent = (ManualResetEvent)e.UserState;
    readCompletedEvent.Set();
    Console.WriteLine("Received callback");
}


static void Complete(bool succeeded)
{
    if (succeeded)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Yeah!");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Boohoo!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In .NET 4.0 there's a nice parallel [Task library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.aspx) that allows you to do things like:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var urls = new[] { "http://www.google.com", "http://www.yahoo.com" };

        Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll(
            urls.Select(url => Task.Factory.StartNew(u => 
            {
                using (var client = new WebClient())
                {
                    return client.DownloadString((string)u);
                }
            }, url)).ToArray(), 
            tasks =>
            {
                var results = tasks.Select(t => t.Result);
                foreach (var html in results)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(html);
                }
        });
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

As you can see for each url in the list a different task is started and once all tasks are completed the callback is invoked and passed the result of all tasks.

Comment: Actually, it'll just make synchronous call in separate worker thread. To solve this, you should make use of `TaskFactory.FromAsync` + `client.BeginGetResponse`. This way, the I/O Completion Ports will be used with no thread blocking.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are better off using the WaitAll approach.  Otherwise you will be processing 10 IAsyncResult callbacks, and using a semaphore to determine that all 10 are finally complete.

Keep in mind that WaitAll is very efficient; it is not like the silliness of having a thread "sleep."  When a thread sleeps, it continues to use processing time.  When a thread is "de-scheduled" because it hit a WaitAll, then the thread no longer consumes any processor time.  It is very efficient.

Comment: In the context of the IIS thread pool, it the thread still in use or would it be put back in the pool like it is for an asynchronous call?